# In what conditions, my if statement will be executed? Its getting executed in a random manner. In what cases my if statement will be true?

Tags: coffeescript

```
i = 0

while i < 8

  j = 0

  while j < 3
    if i & j
      document.write i+" - "+j+"<br/>"
    j++
  i++
```

The output of the above program is
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 1
3 - 2
5 - 1
6 - 2
7 - 1
7 - 2

Comment: What output do you expect and why do you expect it? Do you know what `&` does with numbers? Do you mean to use `&&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To spell out "mu is too short"'s comment, & is the bitwise and operator.  For example, when i=6 and j=2 we have i=110 and j=010 in binary, so i & j = 010 which is nonzero, so the if block is executed and you see 6 - 2 in the output.

Comment: Thank you. I got the logic now.